# How to parse a json file without using json library and json parser

Tags: regex, perl

Below are the input and Output Details

> Input : This is just a sample input and real input is huge and is just in a single line

```
[{"mnemonic":"PT.IA1","ID":"000628"},  {"mnemonic":"EOR.1","ID":"000703"}]
```

> code  : I'm trying to read the file by setting the delimiter as }, so that I get each value,but as its a single line file, its printing everything at one, how do I parse this line by setting a delimiter to this line , is split function 
>   enough to do this job ?

```
our $conf =
{
  chunk_separator   => '\{,',
}
open( FH, "Etot_Data.txt" ) or die $!;
while ( my $chunk = <FH> ){
my $sections = [ split $conf->{chunk_separator}, $chunk ]
   print "$chunk\n";
}
```

> Output

I would want to pick "ID" from each value and prepend "abc." to it 
Final String would look like abc.000628 or abc.000703 and save it in a hash
There's no need of another values except the ID in json string
Is it possible  to read the json file as a normal file and operate on it.
I don't have json parser and I don't have an option to use it

Thanks for the help

Comment: The source code to the JSON parsers on CPAN is available. You can read that to see how they do it. https://metacpan.org/source/MAKAMAKA/JSON-PP-2.27400/lib/JSON/PP.pm

Comment: *I don't have json parser and I don't have an option to use it.* — this sounds unlikely: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=693828

Comment: @Quentin : have been told to do this way :(

Comment: What perl version do you have? 5.14+ has `JSON::PP` in core, so it's already bundled, nothing to install.

Comment: Have you tried pointing out that given the choices of "Well tested, free, third party code you can set up in 5 minutes" and "Hacking something together over a minimum of several hours that will probably break the moment something unexpected arrives in the data", they picked the wrong one?

Comment: By definition, whatever code you will use to do what you want is a parser. So you're asking us to help write you a parser when you say you can't use a parser. It obviously can't be parsers your boss has a problem with, so the first thing you need to do is find out what you must actually avoid and why.

Comment: @Quentin its 5.10

Comment: @LearningCpp — I'm not stevieb

Comment: Apologies @Quentin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can't *install* any external modules, you can sure include it...

Create a `JSON` directory in the same directory your script is in, then copy the contents of the [JSON::PP](https://metacpan.org/source/MAKAMAKA/JSON-PP-2.27400/lib/JSON/PP.pm) module, and put it into a `PP.pm` file inside of the `JSON` directory you just created. Then, in your script, add the current working directory as a library directory: `use lib '.';`, and `use JSON::PP;`.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use lib '.';

use JSON::PP qw(decode_json);

my $json;

{
    local $/;
    open my $fh, '<', 'file.json' or die $!;
    $json = <$fh>;
}

my $perl = decode_json $json;

for (@$perl){
    my $id = 'abc.' . $_->{ID};
    print "$id\n";
}
```

Output:

```
abc.000628
abc.000703
```

If you need to hide the fact you've created an additional module, with only slight finagling, you can make some changes to the module, and include it directly within the script itself.

Note that `JSON::PP` is in Perl core in v5.14+. OP stated in comments that they are on 5.10.

Comment: i have downloaded JSON/JSON-2.90/lib/JSON/backportPP/ ,  would this work ?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't tried it. If it doesn't, use the link I put above, as I tested it as working.

Comment: @LearningCpp... please don't post questions into comments. Also, this is a separate question unrelated to this one, so please ask a new question :)

Comment: Already deleted it , Will post it in a moment , Please check it

Answer (score 5):

Everything that people have said in the comments is true. JSON is a complex data format and expecting to parse it without using the tools that already exist is foolish in the extreme. I urge you to fix whatever roadblock is preventing you from installing and using a JSON parser.

However...

If you only want the ID, and the format is always identical to your sample data, then there is a way to do it. This code is pretty fragile and I can't emphasise enough how much of a bad idea this is. But this code seems to work on your sample data.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

while (<>) {
  foreach my $id (/"ID":"(\d+)"/g) {
    say "abc.$id";
  }
}
```

It reads from STDIN and writes to STDOUT, so call it like this:

```
$ ./parse_json.pl < Etot_data.txt
```

But please get a JSON parser installed.